# Catch a moment when window message is put into queue

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a 3rdparty application (target), which creates a window. I embed that window into my own application by setting parent, changing styles, etc.

The problem is that Spy++ shows target receiving WM_DESTROY two times (in case I close my app). Sometimes this leads to crash of the target.
I want to understand, why the message queue contains 2 WM_DESTROY associated with target window (btw, only 1 WM_NCDESTROY).

To do that I was setting breakpoints at DestroyWindow, PostMessage syscalls, but these functions appear not to be called for the main target window (first one is called only for child windows, second one - with different messages, except WM_DESTROY). I did that in context of both my process and the target process.

So the question is, is there any low-level function which puts messages into the thread message queue? I want to put breakpoint at it and catch a moment when the extra WM_DESTROY is put there.
Smth like PostThreadMessageInternal...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect your actual problem is because you don't un `SetParent()` the window, causing it to be destroyed when your window is closed, then again when it's own shutdown tries to clean up. I haven't posted this as an answer as it doesn't address your stated question.

Comment: Window messages are not always queued. `SendMessage` invokes the target window's `WindowProc` immediately with the specified message.